Databricks workflow dbt tasks high startup time of 3 min
We are running DBT tasks within a workflow.
To run certain DBT models conditionally, we triggered them in separate tasks. Currently, every additional task we create adds 3 or more minutes to the total execution time.
For nerd's pleasure:

In our case, we are waiting 12 times this startup time (36 min) while DBT is only running for a fraction of that. So I am trying to understand what is happening in this startup time and how I could speed it up.

What does actually happen on task startup... Why does creating a clean state take SO long...
Does it install DBT every time, for every task? Does is save time to install dbt to the cluster beforehand (where is the dbt version specified anyway?)?
Cluster choice bad? Cluster: general purpose, 2-8 workers, 13.3LTS Standard_DS4_v2 28GB mem, 8 cores. Used for both dbt-core as for execution.
In the task, the dbt-databricks dependency is specified as >=1.0.0,<2.0.0, might a fixed version speed it up?
I guess that a cluster pool or serverless compute speeds things up, any recommendations?

ps. Because spark just hang when performing everything in parallel, we split it up in these three batches, for now.

Install DBT and dependencies on the cluster ahead of time by adding them to the cluster's init script

@JayashankarGS Will try that, thanks! Is it possible to see that installation in the logs, to check how long that takes?

In cluster advanced options enable logging.

@JayashankarGS, And then it should be visible in the driver logs? I am still trying to set an init script within the companies policies for a shared cluster. Which is limited to storing it in /Volumnes or abfss:// connections... For now I tried adding the dependencies to the "shared cluster" policy, but I see that that just installs the deps as libraries... I have the feeling your init solution is a third, and (hopefully) faster way. In non of these ways I see any pip installs or dbt in any driver or executor log that I made it write.

You will get init script logs when you enable logging in compute advanced options. What task are you adding extra? Is it dbt or different?

Exclusively dbt indeed. So the file should be called "init log"? because I cant find any log file like that using the advanced logging...

check this to see the logs https://docs.databricks.com/en/init-scripts/logs.html
